# How can I remove spaces between two side by side elements on all browsers

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="headmenus">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="search.php">COURSES</a></li>
    <li><a href="vacancies.php">VACANCIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>  
    <li></li>           
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="searchform2">
    <form action="search.php#goto1" method="get" id="headersearch">
       <input type="hidden" name="p" value="0" />
       <input type="text" name="keyword" id="headerkeyword" placeholder="Search any keyword" value="" />
       <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="but1" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

I'd like the headmenus and searchform2 that are positioned side by side to be touching on all browsers i.e. I want to remove spaces between headmenus and searchform2 on all browsers.

Here's the CSS:

```
.searchform2 {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    width:auto !important;
    border:2px solid #616566;
}
.searchform2 input {
    border:2px solid #616566;
    float: left;
/*  margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: auto;
    height:26px;
*/}
.searchform2 .but1 {
    background: url("images/search.png") no-repeat scroll 8px 9px #89AB20;
    border: 0 none !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    float: right !important;

    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 23px !important;
    width: auto !important;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

and here's the headmenus css:

```
.headmenus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0086B2;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 74.3%;
}
.headmenus ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'texgyreadventorregular';
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.headmenus ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 13.35%;
}

.headmenus ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'texgyreadventorregular';
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding:5px 0px;
}

.headmenus ul li:hover {
    background: #89ab20;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headmenus ul li.active {
    background: #89ab20;
}
.headmenus ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 0 none;
    float: right;
    width: auto; !important
}
```

What's happening now is that the headmenus, when I play with its width, I can make sure it touched the input text box but when I switch browsers I need to re-edit that width property

Comment: What do you mean with "touch"? You could click on it on a touch based device, that shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: Ah I mean that I don't want spaces between the elements :)

Comment: headmenu is floating left, searchform is floating right. If u want them to "touch" then set same floating direction for both.

Comment: @atlavis, I didn't understand your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove your `border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;` in `.headmenus ul li`. Then the button will be next to each other without a gap. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNQF9/) for an example (elements are gray for visibility).

`*{box-sizing: border-box;  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;}` takes care of displaying it next to each other in all browsers. Check out [this article from Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) if you are interested in the box-sizing property.

You need to make sure that your `.searchform2` has a `width:25.6% !important;` which makes sure that it fills up all the empty space.

Comment: No It didn't work :( 
What's happening is that the background of headmenus, when I play with its width, I can make sure it touched the input text box but when I switch browsers I need to reedit the width property

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNQF9/1/), is that what you are trying to accomplish? that the search box is always touching the menu?

Comment: Do you see that theres space between the blue background and the input box? I would want to remove it in all browsers

Comment: Then you need to apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to all you elements. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNQF9/2/) for an example. This takes care of the HTML box-model which is not the same for all browsers, border-box fixes this.

Comment: mm it didn't work, still on firefox, there are spaces, I am uploading website, give me a second i can show you

Comment: What happens if you change `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` to `*{box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;}` See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNQF9/7/) for an example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45542/discussion-between-kam-and-roy-schoep)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `box-sizing`. Just set `.searchform2` `width: 25.7%`, move `border` to `.searchform2 form` and add `overflow: hidden` due to floating elements inside.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nNQF9/9/

I'd like to explain something:

total width or height of element = `width/height` + `padding` + `margin` + `border-width`

For instance if is set `width: 50%` and additionaly `border: 2px soid whatever` then total width of element is `50% + 4px`.

If we want widths to perfectly fit some ratio and we need borders, padding or margins then we need more cointainers:

```
<div class="cointainer_left_75_percents">
   <div class="container_with_borders_paddings_margins">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
<div class="cointainer_right_25_percents">
   <div class="container_with_borders_paddings_margins">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Or we can use **experimental** property [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) which changes impact of borders, paddings and margins on total widths and heights.